# Using Open-URI to fetch XML and the best practice in case of problems with a remote url not returning/timing out?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, timeout, open-uri

Current code works as long as there is no remote error:

```
def get_name_from_remote_url
      cstr = "http://someurl.com"
      getresult = open(cstr, "UserAgent" => "Ruby-OpenURI").read
      doc = Nokogiri::XML(getresult)
      my_data = doc.xpath("/session/name").text
      #  => 'Fred' or 'Sam' etc
      return my_data
end
```

But, what if the remote URL times out or returns nothing? How I detect that and return nil, for example?

And, does Open-URI give a way to define how long to wait before giving up? This method is called while a user is waiting for a response, so how do we set a max timeoput time before we give up and tell the user "sorry the remote server we tried to access is not available right now"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open-URI is convenient, but that ease of use means they're removing the access to a lot of the configuration details the other HTTP clients like Net::HTTP allow.

It depends on what version of Ruby you're using. For 1.8.7 you can use the [Timeout](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/timeout/1.9.2/frames) module. From the docs:

```
require 'timeout'
begin
status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
  getresult = open(cstr, "UserAgent" => "Ruby-OpenURI").read
}
rescue Timeout::Error => e
  puts e.to_s
end
```

Then check the length of getresult to see if you got any content:

```
if (getresult.empty?)
  puts "got nothing from url"
end
```

If you are using Ruby 1.9.2 you can add a [`:read_timeout => 10`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/open-uri/1.9.2/frames) option to the `open()` method.

---

Also, your code could be tightened up and made a bit more flexible. This will let you pass in a URL or default to the currently used URL. Also read Nokogiri's [NodeSet](http://rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/1.4.4.2/frames) docs to understand the difference between `xpath`, `/`, `css` and `at`, `%`, `at_css`, `at_xpath`:

```
def get_name_from_remote_url(cstr = 'http://someurl.com')
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(cstr, 'UserAgent' => 'Ruby-OpenURI'))

  # xpath returns a nodeset which has to be iterated over
  # my_data = doc.xpath('/session/name').text #  => 'Fred' or 'Sam' etc  

  # at returns a single node
  doc.at('/session/name').text
end
```